# Vim auto complete command search external file

Tags: vim

I'm looking for a way to configure my vimrc file or set variables that can search external file for auto completion in Vim

For example:
I want the words completion in following directory:

```
/home/code/mycompletionfile.txt
```

By the way:

I do know I can use dictionary to include a file, but I'm looking for a way to use directory so that all the files under the directory can be searched for auto completion.

I knew there are many awesome plugins out there and I did install some plugins before, but some plugins slows down my Vim significantly.

**This is what I did so far:**

I try set path variable in vim:

Add my path that contains all my files so that Vim can search all the file in the path for auto completion

Try:

```
:set path+=/home/code/
```

Try:

```
:set path+=/home/code/*
```

Try:

```
:set path+=/home/code/.
```

None of them are working.

I do know **complete variable** has many options in Vim:

```
complete: .,w,b,u,t,i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `'path'` option is completely irrelevant.

Here is the relevant part of `:help 'complete'`:

```
k{dict} scan the file {dict}.  Several "k" flags can be given,
        patterns are valid too.  For example:
                :set cpt=k/usr/dict/*,k~/spanish
```